# livewire model is not working when updating input field from javascrip

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i show value in input feild using javascript after some calculation
values are populating in input feilds properly [populating data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxCIF.png) but when i submit the form to save data in database,the error has coming "{Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'restAmountOfDesign' cannot be null}"

i want to save the data in database. Target all the input feild  and save the data

Comment: Begin by sharing some code so we can see what you're trying to do.